# 2.8 Transparency in Solid Viewport Shading

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

When setting the Alpha value to anything but 1 this happens. Setting it back to 1, everything goes back to normal.

[image]

Comment: You might try changing material's, "Blend Mode," if you haven't already: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#blend-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly recommend you update to the newest version of Blender and AMD graphics driver. 2.8x has well-known bugs and glitches related to several versions of AMD graphic drivers like this:

[AMD GPU Material in "material preview mode" and "rendered mode", is entirely gray as background. Only outline is displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)

https://developer.blender.org/T67615

[Viewports broken on RX 580](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204044/viewports-broken-on-rx-580)

Comment: I literally have a RX 580 lol